# overloaded method value apply with alternatives error in scala

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark, compiler-errors, aws-glue

I have the following code as a part of my glue job:

```
def forTxnType(dynamicRecord: DynamicRecord): DynamicRecord = {
val s = dynamicRecord.getField("transactiondirection")
val s_out = dynamicRecord.getField("transfermechanism")
val s_in = dynamicRecord.getField("terminalid").mkString("")
val m_Wire = List("FWWRD", "WTPCT", "WTROL")
val m_ACH = List("9CACH","9DACH","WTB19","WTB20","WTCN0","WTCN9","WTFP0","WTLEG","WTM20","WTP20","WTPMD","WTSNR","WTSPN","WTT20","WTTEF") 
val m_ACAT = List("NSTFR","TSTFR","NSADJ") 
val m_Check = List("MGRCF","WTFEE","WTFP0","WTLEG","WTM20","WTP20","WTROL","WTSPN","WTTEF","Z9CHK") 
val m_CashJournal = List("AUDEP","AUFEE","CSCSG","WTB20","WTBYP","WTCN0","WTCN9")

val etype = if(s.equals("Outgoing")){
    s_out
} else {
if(m_Check.contains(s_in)){
        "Check"
    }
    else if(m_CashJournal.contains(s_in)){
        "Cash_journal"
    }
    else if(m_Wire.contains(s_in)){
        "Wire"
    }
    else if(m_ACH.contains(s_in)){
        "ACH"
    }
    else if(m_ACAT.contains(s_in)){
        "ACAT"
    }
    else{
        "NoType"
    }
   }

dynamicRecord.addField("transactionType", StringNode(etype))
dynamicRecord
}
```

It is giving the below error on the line - dynamicRecord.addField("transactionType", StringNode(etype)):

overloaded method value apply with alternatives

Comment: Can you accept + upvote if below solutions helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Return type of `def getField( path : String ) : Option[Any]` is `Option`

`StringNode` will only take data of type `String` but your `etype` data type is of type `Any`, because of this you are getting error `overloaded method value apply with alternatives` to fix this issue change `s_out` to `s_out.get` in your if block.

Check below code.

```
val etype = if(s.equals("Outgoing")){
    s_out.get // Add .get here
} else {...}
```